# Change appearance of list items so that they appear like columns like a table

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of li tags and each item has a title and description.

```
<ul>
  <li>$title[0] $description[0]</li>
  <li>$title[1] $description[1]</li>
  ...
  <li>$title[n] $description[n]</li>
</ul>
```

I want them to be aligned so that they appear like columns in a table, like the following example:

```
$title[0]    $description[0]
$title[1]    $description[1]
...
$title[n]    $description[n]
```

Comment: This really isn't enough information for us to help you. Please post more info, maybe some code which you have tried already, and a reason why you are trying to do this as you might be going about it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm assuming from your question you have a list of li elements and for each you want to output textn where n is the one-based index of the item in the list. If so how about...</strike>

```
$("li").each(function(i) { 
  $(this).text("text"+(i+1)); 
});
```

**EDIT** In response to your updated question you could do this using something like...

```
$("li").each(function() { 
  // Use regular expressions to extract the numerical index from the text... 
  // This appears to be what you intend from your question
  var index = $(this).text().replace(/title(\d+)/, "$1");
  // Append an element containing the description to the li element
  $(this).append("<span class=\"col2\">description-" + index + "</span>"); 
});
```

And then use CSS to position, something like...

```
/* Used to stop float overflowing the list item */
li { overflow: hidden; }
/* Float the col2 element to the right with a consistent width so
 * all col2 elements appear aligned */
li .col2 { float: right; width: 25%; }
```

**EDIT** Ignore the JavaScript above, I think you just need the HTML and CSS. To get a list to appear as a table...

```
<li>
    <span class="col1">Title 1</span>
    <span class="col2">Description 1</span>
</li>
```

Then use floats to position the items, it will not work exactly the way tables work in the way tables automatically divide up the space but it will likely have the effect you need. The CSS example above is one way to do it, you can use opposing floats...

```
li { overflow: hidden; /* Row level styling */ }
li .col1 { float: left; width: 75%; }
li .col2 { float: right; width: 25%; }
```

Or you can stack floats next to each other

```
li { overflow: hidden; /* Row level styling */ }
li .col1 { float: left; width: 25%; }
li .col2 { float: left; width: 50%; }
li .col3 { float: left; width: 25%; }
```

I've done a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/g8Xkp/

Comment: please take again a look at my question, I want to put all the description on the same "column" but witout use a table only li elements

Comment: Good answer to an awful question. +1

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know the question isn't great, I'll edit it once it becomes clear exactly what the OP is asking.

Comment: +1 Nice answer, seems to be what the OP was trying to get at

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to remove the list style of the list? Then use CSS like this:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to amend the text of each `LI` element within your list. You should adjust the selector to target specific lists if you have more than one, as currently this will target all `LI` elements within the page. (i.e. `$('li.menu')`)

```
$('li').each(function(index, element){ 
   //Amend each element here
   $(element).text('new text');
});
```